# Do array properties cause memory allocation on the heap?

Tags: c#, arrays, properties, garbage-collection, heap-memory

Consider the following:

```
public class FooBar {
    public int[] SomeNumbers {
        get { return _someNumbers; }
        private set;
    }

    private int[] _someNumbers;

    public FooBar() {
        _someNumbers = new int[2];
        _someNumbers[0] = 1;
        _someNumbers[1] = 2;
    }
}

// in some other method somewhere...

FooBar foobar = new FooBar();
Debug.Log(foobar.SomeNumbers[0]);
```

What I am wondering is, does calling the SomeNumbers property cause a heap allocation; basically does it cause a copy of the array to be created, or is it just a pointer?

I ask because I am trying to resolves some GC issues I have due to functions that return arrays, and I want to make sure my idea of caching some values like this will actually make a difference

Comment: Arrays are passed/returned by reference, so yes, your property would basically just be returning a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are always reference types, so yes, it is "basically returning a pointer".

If you are trying to debug memory issues I recommend using a memory profiler. There is one [built in to Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264934.aspx) or you can use a 3rd party one (I personally like [DotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/), it has a 5 day free trial). Using a profiler will help you identify what is creating memory objects and what is keeping memory objects alive.

Comment: Thanks Scott; I am going to mark this answered. As for profiling, this is an issue in Unity revealed form it;s profiler. I know what is causing the GC spikes (I make hundreds of new arrays every frame). I just wanted to make sure that my solution would not just be a different way to over-allocate to the heap. haha

Comment: Unity 5 now includes it's profiler in it's free edition (it was only in the paid version in 4), it is also useful to figure out what scripts are creating the arrays.

Comment: Yeah I know; I am using it. A deep profile revealed where the spikes occur; I have a set of methods that all create small arrays, but hundreds of times a frame (they return arrays). I am trying to alter them all now to not return arrays, and to use cached values smartly

Comment: Ok, cool. It was not clear at first if you found this problem from profiling or if you where just assuming that the array creation was the source of your problem.